# jQuery AJAX request 'parseerror' error on JSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, matrix

When sending an AJAX request to get a JSON object, which specifically is an nxn matrix, I get a 'parseerror' error. This only occurs for really large matrices (800x800). The AJAX request works perfectly for smaller sized matrices (200x200). I also commented out `dataType: "json"` and it works, but since I run the code twice in succession, it breaks the second time.

```
var dir = "filename"; 
$.ajax({

        type: "POST",
        url: "getSimMatrix.php?dir=" + dir + "%2F",
        dataType: "json",
        //timeout:80000, //80 seconds
        error: function(x, t, m) {
            if(t==="timeout") {
                alert("timeout occurred");
            } else {
                alert(t);
            }
        },
        success: function(data) {
            console.log("matrix done");
        }
    });
```

Edit: Here's a sample JSON object that is created:

```
[[0,4,3,2,5,6,1],[1,2,5,3,0,4,6],[2,1,0,5,3,4,6],[3,0,4,5,2,1,6],[4,0,3,6,5,2,1],[5,3,2,0,1,4,6],[6,4,0,3,2,5,1]]
```

Comment: what is the returned content?

Comment: Are you sure your JSON is correctly formatted in the case of large metrices? Why don't you put up one such sample?

Comment: An n x n array, which is calculated by opening n files in the directory and doing some math on the contents in them.

Comment: The `parseerror` only happens because your code requests `json`, and non-JSON is being returned. Has nothing to do with your code, and everything to do with the payload. Show us your "JSON".

Comment: Is that the last payload from the server before the error, as shown by the Network panel in your browser? Because nothing here should cause `parseerror`.

Comment: Show us your PHP Code

Comment: Here's my PHP code: http://pastebin.com/ht6XVjce

Comment: @Amadan Here's the information from the network panel: http://i.imgur.com/RCssDZQ.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. Putting this code in my PHP file will use an unlimited memory on the server. Not quite ideal, but it works. I was getting an "Allowed memory size of _ bytes exhausted (tried to allocate _ bytes)" error.

```
//Removes the memory limit on the server
ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');
```

Answer (score 0):

You must return `json` from `server side`, check that you have returned valid json by using [json-encode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) like,

```
    // your code
    echo json_encode($matrixArray);
    return;
?>
```

Comment: I just change my code from `print json_encode($simMatrix);` to 
`echo json_encode($simMatrix);
return;`
Yet I still get a parseerror.